# DOM Get page content after redirect

Tags: php, dom

How can I get page content via the DOM after redirect?
I need get ID from URL but first URL is something like this:

> www.example.com/product?parametr1=a&parametr2=b&parametr3=c

When i put this url to browser, page is redirect to:

> www.example.com/product/name/**ID**

Comment: another request should do it…

Comment: Is this in the client browser or on a server?

Comment: Script is on my localhost, url is a web on internet. I need this in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If the final page is that one with the ID then this should to the trick:

```
var url = window.location.href;
var id = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
console.log("Here is the ID: " + id);
```

Comment: but how can i do this in php?

Comment: It looks like your site is using something like `mod_rewrite` to have /ID path without a .php extension so we need more details to do it by PHP such as the `.htaccess` file content